# Composite C1: How to make the page tree to display UrlTitle instead of Title (Solution)

Tags: c1-cms

When Composite C1 displays the tree of sites and pages in the Content perspective, it uses the page Title property as the node label. This is not always comfortable, especially when the pages are translated to different cultures, so you can't even read those titles and quickly find the page you are looking for.
The idea is to use the UrlTitle as the label, so every tree node would represent a part of the page URL.
See the solution below.

Comment: When you translate pages, the URL should be localized as well - urls are also required to be human readable in that language.

Comment: @PauliØsterø, I assume you know what you are talking about. What is your experience in localization of sites? Which languages did you translate URLs to?

Comment: @PauliØsterø, I have some experience with French, German, Italian, Spanish, and also with Turkish, Russian, and Arabic.
I guess you understand it's hard to make human-readable URLs with Russian and Arabic, as their abcs are not based on Latin. However, even those European languages as French, German, and Spanish have their specific chars, that do not exist in ASCII: ç, ß, ñ, etc.
So, how do you make sure that URLs are readable?

Comment: Unicode characters have been supported for a long time in modern browsers, so i don't understand your question. Urls are always translated into each language the site is on. https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%9C%84%ED%82%A4%EB%B0%B1%EA%B3%BC:%EB%8C%80%EB%AC%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to recompile the assemblies, so my hack is ugly, but affects only javascript and aspx.

1. Edit */Composite/scripts/compressed/top.js*.

   Find there `SystemTreeNodeBinding.prototype.onBindingAttach=function(){` and inject the following code at the beginning of this function:

   ```
   if(window.treeNodeProcessor)window.treeNodeProcessor(this.node);
   ```

   Now you can modify the tree node before it is displayed; you just need to create your global function `treeNodeProcessor`.
2. Edit */Composite/top.aspx* (top.aspx.cs is affected as well, so save them together).

   At the end of the `head` element add your javascript:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function byKey(key) {
           return function(p) {
               return p.Key == key;
           }
       }

       window.treeNodeTitles = {
   <% WriteTreeNodeTitles(); %>
           "": ""
       };

       window.treeNodeProcessor = function(node) {
           if(node._data.PropertyBag) {
               var uri = node._data.PropertyBag.find(byKey('Uri')).Value;
               node._data.Label = window.treeNodeTitles[uri] || node._data.Label;
           }
       }

   </script>
   ```

   Unfortunately, there's no UrlTitle in the `node` object passed to `treeNodeProcessor`. However, every page `node` has `PropertyBag` that stores a value like *~/page(a9d30645-02f7-4412-bd4e-6f3a02782481)* under key *Uri*. So, you have to query the UrlTitle on your own, what is made in method WriteTreeNodeTitles (see below).
3. Edit */Composite/top.aspx.cs*.

   Add new method:

   ```
   protected void WriteTreeNodeTitles()
   {
       using (var conn = new DataConnection())
       {
           foreach( string line in conn.Get<IPage>().Select( p => "            \"~/page(" + p.Id.ToString().ToLower() + ")\": \"" + p.UrlTitle + "\",\r\n" ) )
           {
               Response.Write( line );
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   You have to add few usings, of course:

   ```
   using System.Linq;
   using Composite.Data;
   using Composite.Data.Types;
   ```

So, now your top.aspx contains the mapping of page guid-like urls to UrlTitles, and the treeNodeProcessor function that uses that mapping for modifying your page tree.

Comment: Very ugly indeed. If you're serious about making changes to the product you should fork the repository and maintain the changes in a documented way which can be preserved during upgrades.

Comment: It's just a question of (my) time. The way you have described is obviously the right one, while mine is not; however mine takes 15 minutes, while yours takes amount of time I cannot afford myself at the moment.